# Figure It Out With Ease

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

What goes next in the number sequence?

9, 9, 10, 9, 10, 9, 9, 9, 5, 8, 6, 10, 11, 8, ?

Hint 1

> The title of this puzzle is a massive hint as to where I got these numbers from

Hint 2

> When you find this number in question, try experimenting with the addition of the digits in the number

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> $e=2.71828182845904523536028747135\dots$
> Break digits into pairs and add: 27, 18, 28,..., 74, 71 → 9, 9, 10,..., 11, 8.
> The next number is $3+5=\boxed8$.